# Reference to composite key in another table in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, foreign-keys

I have the following script for creating three tables in MariaDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `booking_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `occupants` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `room_type_requested` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nights` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `arrival_time` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`booking_id`),
  KEY `room_no` (`room_no`),
  KEY `guest_id` (`guest_id`),
  KEY `room_type_requested` (`room_type_requested`,`occupants`),
  CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_no`) REFERENCES `room` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`guest_id`) REFERENCES `guest` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`room_type_requested`) REFERENCES `room_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`room_type_requested`, `occupants`) REFERENCES `rate` (`room_type`, `occupancy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `rate` (
  `room_type` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `occupancy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room_type`,`occupancy`),
  CONSTRAINT `rate_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_type`) REFERENCES `room_type` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `room_type` (
  `id` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to add another table, `accommodation_payments`. I want it to be linked to the `amount` in the `rate` table. How to define my foreign key (lets call it `room_type_booked`)?

[image: ERD]

Is it better to link it to the `booking` table or to the `room_type` table similar to how the FK `room_type_requested` in the `booking` table was created (see the latter option in the ERD above)?

Why are there are two constraints for `room_type_requested` in `booking`?

```
CREATE TABLE `accommodation_payments` (
  `acc_pmt_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_type_booked` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_method` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `pmt_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`acc_pmt_id`),
  KEY `room_type_booked` (`room_type_booked`),

  CONSTRAINT `acc_pmt_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_type_booked`) REFERENCES `booking` (`room_type_requested`));
```

Comment: Are rows in `accommodation_payments` supposed to be for a specific booking? If you reference `booking.room_type_requested`, which booking does it apply to?

Comment: yes, they are for a specific booking.

Comment: Then I would add a column in `accommodation_payments` that references `booking.booking_id`, the primary key of the booking table. It does no good to reference `booking_type_requested`, because (I assume) any booking type value occurs on many booking rows, and it would be ambiguous which booking the payment applied to.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) An ERD is an image of DDL text.